# The c++ new operator in default arguments and its side-effects

Tags: c++

I have a question about default arguments in c++. If I a have a function like this:

```
int foo(int* obj = new Int(4)) {
    /* Stuff with obj. */
}
```

Now, of course, the integer is here just used as an example, but the question is if I were to provide a value for the argument like this:

```
int x = 2;
foo(&x);
```

will the expression `obj = new Int(4)` still be evaluated even though I provided a value for the argument and therefore allocated memory which I then can't read from anymore?

Comment: The default argument will be evaluated only if the function will be called without an argument.

Comment: No then the `new` will not be executed. But beware, if no arguments is passed you can have a memory leak if you do not `delete` the pointer. And if you do `delete` the pointer, how can you tell the difference between a pointer passed to a non-new allocated object and one allocated with new? (Hint: You can't!) In short, using `new` for a default  argument is a *very* bad idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, default arguments are only used when there is no argument passed to them. `new` won't be invoked and thus there will be no memory allocation. Also, as Some programmer dude said you have a memory leak if you do not clean up at some point either inside (or outside) the function body.

Answer (score 5):

Using a `new` expression as a default value for an argument, as in

```
 int foo(int *obj = new int(4));
```

is an extremely bad idea, since there are possible use cases that behave inconsistently with each other, and a number of bad possible outcomes.

Let's say, for sake of discussion that the implementation of `foo()` does

```
 delete obj;
```

That is okay if the caller does either of

```
 foo();             //  default argument is a new expression
 foo(new int(2));
```

but causes undefined behaviour if the caller does one or more of;

```
 foo(&some_int);      //  some_int is a variable local to the caller
 foo(new int[2]);     //   dynamically allocates an array
```

Conversely, let's say that `foo()` does NOT do  `delete obj`.   In this case, either of these statements

```
 foo();
 foo(new int(3));
 foo(new int [2]);      // dynamically allocates an array
```

cause a memory leak, and

```
  foo(&some_int);
```

will probably work correctly (assuming `foo()` does not invoke undefined behaviour in other ways).

The real problem is that `foo()` has no way (within bounds of standard C++) of detecting which of the above the caller does.   So there is a real risk of either undefined behaviour or a memory leak, unless the caller does EXACTLY the "right thing"  (where "right thing" means not causing a memory leak or undefined behaviour).   And, since there are more options to do the wrong thing, odds are the caller will NOT do exactly the right thing.     Bear in mind that programmers are notoriously terrible at reading documentation, so relying on documentation is a poor way to ensure the caller (or the programmer writing code in the caller) does what is needed to avoid problems like the above.

Comment: Even if I don't use ``new`` in my default arguments I still can't check if the object which has been passed by the caller is allocated on the heap, therefore the caller must handle the memory and delete the object accordingly, right? This would be problematic because a hierarchy of objects is created and the caller would either need to implement an algorithm which deletes every child or keep a reference to the children in some way. Both of these "solutions" would require lots of code which also has to be repeated. Is there any way to check during compile time how an object has been allocated?

Comment: Within bounds of C++, there is not.